Как в LaTeX поставить одну большую квадратную скобку?
Нашла как поставить большую фигурную скобку (одну перед системой), а вот большую квадратную - нет
$$|x| =\begin{cases}
    x,\quad x \geq 0 \\
    -x, \quad x < 0
  \end{cases}$$

Имею ввиду вот такие скобки:


Чёт это нифига не markdown, а latex)))

точно, спасибо большое, делаю конспекты по матеше в Obsidian и все перепутала)

Может классическая конструкция \left[ ... \right. ?

Как-то так:
$$
|x| = \left[
\begin{align}
   x, \quad x \geq 0 \\
  -x, \quad x < 0
\end{align}
\right.
$$


